# Why does std::when_any use std::tuple rather than std::vector as its result type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, standards

Cited from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any)

`std::when_any` is defined as follows:

```
template<class Sequence>
struct when_any_result
{
    std::size_t index;
    Sequence    futures;
};

template<class InputIt>
auto when_any(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    -> future<when_any_result<std::vector<
        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>>;

template<class... Futures>
auto when_any(Futures&&... futures)
    -> future<when_any_result<std::tuple<std::decay_t<Futures>...>>>;
```

What makes me confused is why does the last form not use `std::vector` as its result type?

The result contains an `index` field, which can be used to retrieve the ready future. To me, `std::tuple` is hard to iterate via `index` at run-time, but `std::vector` is easy to do so.

Is there any rationale behind for such a design?

Comment: "Is there any rationale behind for such a design?" - Very probably *yes*. Things rarely make it into the standard without a rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `InputIt first, InputIt last` is an iterator range. It defines an input range over a sequence of elements of the same type.

This `Futures&&... futures` is a variadic template. It defines a series of parameters of potentially different types.

Both of these restrict their input values to some form of future, but the latter one can take different kinds of futures that result in different types of values. A `vector<T>` is a homogeneous container; it *cannot* represent values of different types (unless it's a `vector<any>`, but that just makes it cumbersome and inefficient to use).